# How can I coloring selected text in a cell by macro?

Tags: excel

I want to use shortcut to coloring selected text in a cell by macro. However, the only thing I can do is to  coloring selected text in a cell. For example:

```
Sub Bold14PtMacro()
    With Selection.Font
        .Name = "Calibri"
        .Size = 30
        .Strikethrough = False
        .Superscript = False
        .Subscript = False
        .OutlineFont = False
        .Shadow = False
        .Underline = xlUnderlineStyleNone
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .ThemeFont = xlThemeFontMinor
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True
End Sub
```

Is there any method to accomplish this funciton?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could of course color all the text in the selected cell, but I don't think that there is any programmatic way to specify which part of the text in a cell is being selected. One problem is that, without being in edit mode, I don't think that you *can* be selecting just part of the text, and VBA won't run when in edit mode. Perhaps you could have a userform with a textbox popup, populated by the text in a cell, and use userform event-handlers to do what you want on the text in the userform, transferring back to the cell when the form is closed.